# How to disable SSLv3 for embedded Jetty server for Ring application?

Tags: clojure, jetty, embedded-jetty, ring, poodle-attack

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26388531/173497) to the Java version of this question – [How to disable the SSLv3 protocol in Jetty to prevent Poodle Attack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26382540/how-to-disable-the-sslv3-protocol-in-jetty-to-prevent-poodle-attack) – covers how to do this, but what's the equivalent minimal code to do the same for a Clojure web application using Ring and the Ring Jetty adapter, which uses embedded Jetty version 7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I added to the namespace file containing my project's `-main` function:

```
(defn is-jetty-ssl-connector?
  [^org.eclipse.jetty.server.Connector c]
  (= (.getName (type c)) "org.eclipse.jetty.server.ssl.SslSelectChannelConnector"))

(defn jetty-configurator
  [jetty-server]
  (doseq [c (filter is-jetty-ssl-connector? (.getConnectors jetty-server))]
    (.addExcludeProtocols (.getSslContextFactory c) (into-array String ["SSLv3"]))))
```

Added to the options map of the `jetty/run-jetty` function call in my `-main` function:

```
:configurator jetty-configurator
```

I confirmed that this seems to work using a cURL command like the following:

```
curl -v3 -X HEAD https://localhost:443
```

Comment: Or just run Jetty 9.2.7 and get that exclusion as default behavior / configuration.

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt [I don't think the Ring Jetty adapter will be using Jetty 9 for a while](https://github.com/ring-clojure/ring/issues/177).

Comment: Jetty 7 and Jetty 8 were EOL (End of Life) back in 2014.  - filed a bug with ring about this - https://github.com/ring-clojure/ring/issues/183

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt fair enough!