# Disabling ssl v3 in activemq admin console

Tags: ssl, activemq-classic

How to disable ssl v3 in activemq Admin console (port 8161)? I did not found any document on line.

In my jetty.xml file I can see below lines:

```xml
<bean id="SecureConnector" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ssl.SslSelectChannelConnector">
    <property name="port" value="8161" />
    <property name="keystore" value="file:${activemq.conf}/broker.ks" />
    <property name="password" value="password" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

ActiveMQ uses a basic spring wired jetty server for the admin web-gui. Use the methods available in Jetty documentation - or look at this [SO.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26382540/how-to-disable-the-sslv3-protocol-in-jetty-to-prevent-poodle-attack)

SslSelectChannelConnector takes a `SslContextFactory` as constructor arg. That factory has a `excludeProtocols` property which you can feed with "sslv3".

Wire that up in spring should be straight forward.

Comment: Thanks for you help . Really appreciated with the solution .