# How to test sslv3 is enable in jetty 8 or not

Tags: ssl, jetty, poodle-attack, sslv3

My task is to disable sslv3 in my jetty-8-1-14. I went through this link: [How to disable sslv3 in jetty8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26382540/how-to-disable-the-sslv3-protocol-in-jetty-to-prevent-poodle-attack)

But to change the code I need to check the current status of sslv3 for jetty8 server.

Is there any command by which I can get whether the sslv3 is enable or not?

Answer (score 0):

There's no command that Jetty provides, or JMX exposed MBean, to check this.

However, you can use external tool like [ssllabs.com/ssltest/](https://ssllabs.com/ssltest/) or [`openssl's s_client`](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/71457/how-can-i-verify-that-sslv3-protocol-is-disabled)